# How do I refer to an appended item in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, append

I want to create and append an item in jquery, while saving a reference to it.

```
 var buy = "<img src='img/buy-now.png' />";      
 var $buy = $(buy).appendTo("body");
 $buy.html("hello");
```

I was expecting something like the above to work. Any ideas?

Comment: That should work...what is `$cloney`?

Comment: What are you expecting the above to do? Need more information.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I then want to use $buy as the object that I've appended.

Comment: Also, I'm aware I can chain, but I want to refer to it later on...

Comment: See my answer below...I think the problem isn't your reference, but your specific `.html()` call on an invalid element in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `$buy` *is* the object you've appended, you're just doing an invalid operation.  `<img />` is a self-closing tag, there is no HTML inside it, so [`.html("something")`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will have no effect.

If you meant to set the tooltip, use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like this:

```
$buy.attr('alt', 'hello');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the variable `$buy` will save the reference of the element and the jQuery object.

**Edit:**
`$buy.html("hello");` will add "hello" inside the image tag, however it will be hidden on the screen since the image is being displayed.