# How can I reference an element after I have appended it using javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, append

I am doing some basic javascripting and am creating a 3 column table created by javascript sourced from an xml. The table is created by appending all the data in rows via javascript.

The first column has an input checkbox, created via javascript, that if ticked fetches a price from the third column on that row and adds all the prices of the rows selected to give a price total.

The problem I am having is I don't seem to be able to reference the appended information to obtain the information in the related price column (third column).

I have attached both the function I am using to create the table which is working and the function I am using to try and add it up which isnt working.

I found the following two articles [Getting access to a jquery element that was just appended to the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107267/getting-access-to-a-jquery-element-that-was-just-appended-to-the-dom) and [How do I refer to an appended item in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122125/how-do-i-refer-to-an-appended-item-in-jquery) but I am using only javascript not jquery and would like a javascript only solution if possible.

Can you help? - its just the calculateBill function that isn't working as expected.

Thank you in advance

```
function addSection() {
    var section = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("section");

    for (i=0; i < section.length; i++) {

        var sectionName = section[i].getAttribute("name");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.setAttribute("colspan", "3");
        td.setAttribute("class","level");
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sectionName));

        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.appendChild(td);
        tbody.appendChild(tr);

        var server = section.item(i).getElementsByTagName("server");

        for (j=0; j < server.length; j++) { 
            var createTR = document.createElement("tr");
            var createTD = document.createElement("td");
            var createInput = document.createElement("input");
            createInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            createInput.setAttribute("id", "checkInput");
            createTD.appendChild(createInput);
            createTR.appendChild(createTD);

            var item = server[j].getElementsByTagName("item")[0].innerHTML;
            var createTD2 = document.createElement("td");
            var createText = document.createTextNode(item);
            createTD2.appendChild(createText);
            createTR.appendChild(createTD2);

            var price = server[j].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML;
            var createTD3 = document.createElement("td");
            var createText2 = document.createTextNode("£" + price);
            createTD3.appendChild(createText2);
            createTR.appendChild(createTD3);
            tbody.appendChild(createTR);
        }
    }
}

onload = addSection();

function calculateBill() {
    var finalBill = 0.0;
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkInput");
    for (i=0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
        if (checkBox[i].checked) {
            var parentTR = checkBox[i].parentNode;
            var priceTD = parentTR.getElementsByTagName('td')[2];
            finalBill += parseFloat(priceTD.firstChild.data);
        }
    }
    return Math.round(finalBill*100.0)/100.0;
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onClick=document.forms[0].textTotal.value=calculateBill();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `x.appendChild(y)`, `y` is the DOM node that you are appending.  You can reference it via javascript either before or after appending it.  You don't have to find it again if you just hang on to the DOM reference.

So, in this piece of code:

```
        var createInput = document.createElement("input");
        createInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        createInput.setAttribute("id", "checkInput");
        createTD.appendChild(createInput);
```

`createInput` is the input element.  You can reference it with javascript at any time, either before or after you've inserted it in the DOM.

In this piece of code:

```
        var price = server[j].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML;
        var createTD3 = document.createElement("td");
        var createText2 = document.createTextNode("£" + price);
        createTD3.appendChild(createText2);
        createTR.appendChild(createTD3);
        tbody.appendChild(createTR);
```

You're creating a `<td>` element and putting a price into it.  `createTD3` is that particular `<td>` element.

---

If you want to be able to find that element sometime in the future long after the block of code has run, then I'd suggest you give it an identifying id or class name such that you can use some sort of DOM query to find it again.  For example, you could put a class name on it `"price"` and then be able to find it again later:

```
        var price = server[j].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML;
        var createTD3 = document.createElement("td");
        createTD3.className = "price";
        var createText2 = document.createTextNode("£" + price);
        createTD3.appendChild(createText2);
        createTR.appendChild(createTD3);
        tbody.appendChild(createTR);
```

Then, you could find all the price elements again with:

```
tbody.querySelectorAll(".price");
```

Assuming tbody is the table where you put all these elements (since that's what you're using in your enclosed code).  If the table itself had an id on it like `id="mainData"`, then you could simply use

```
document.querySelectorAll("#mainData .price")
```

to get all the price elements.

---

FYI, here's a handy function that goes up the DOM tree starting from any node and finds the first node that is of a particular tag type:

```
function findParent(node, tag) {
    tag = tag.upperCase();
    while (node && node.tagName !== tag) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return node;    
}

// example usage:
var row, priceElement, price;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkInput");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    // go up to the parent chain to find out row
    row = findParent(checkboxes[i], "tr");
    // look in this row for the price
    priceElement = row.querySelectorAll(".price")[0];
    // parse the price out of the price element
    price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerHTML.replace(/^[^\d\.]+/, ""));
    // do something here with the price
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. What I was hoping to do was find the identity of the selected input fields, go up to the parent TR and then find the third TD in that row. Does that make sense or am I doing this in a backwards way?

Comment: @EamonYates - see what I've added to my answer.  It would be better to attach a known class name and use that to find it rather than count rows or columns.  But, if you have some reference in the table and want to find price that corresponds to that reference, the general concept you have is right.  You go up the parent chain to a common parent (often a row in a table) and then use something like `tr.querySelectorAll()` to find the element you're looking for in that row.  I highly recommend you use class names on different elements to make it easy to find things.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 I see what you are saying and also just realised that my checkbox's were using ID's instead of classes. You are right in thinking that my goal is to get specific rows that would be selected by the input checkbox being ticked. For some reason, my code doesn't seem to recognise the class or ID that I am setting in my javascript code but does recognise it inside my html. I cant work out why?

Comment: @EamonYates - id's have to be unique in the document so if you have more than one with the same id, that will not work.  Is there a way to talk more specifically about a specific piece of code/HTML that you're having trouble with rather than such a generic conversation?  I'm thinking of a description that starts with "an event occurs on this DOM element" and then I want to find this related DOM element and here's what the generated HTML looks like and here's the code I'm trying that isn't working.

Comment: I can try my best, please feel free to dig into it further if i'm not clear. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: First I have the table created from the function addSection(). All the elements I am struggling with are based in the function calculateBill(). Inside this function I am creating the finalBill variable to set that to 0 initially. Then I create var checkBox = document.getElementByID("checkInput"); This is the id that I have set earlier in the script via setAttribute ("ID", "checkInput"); to the input type="checkbox". I am expecting at this point that the code returns all checkbox TD's

Comment: @EamonYates - that is your first problem.  `getElementById()` only returns a single element.  You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.  Change the id to a class name of `"checkInput"` and use `document.querySelectorAll(".checkInput")` to get all your checkboxes.  That will return all checkbox elements.  If you want the containing `<td>` or `<tr>`, you will have to go up the parent chain to find those.

Comment: Thanks jfriend, I have changed the items now so it is setting a class rather than an ID and I am gathering the class via your suggestion but I still can't get it to work. When I am writing the code out, the code editor is also suggesting that I cant use querySelectorAll at that stage. This could be just the code editor being funny though. :-) From your answer above will the parent of this class return the TD not the TR?

Comment: @EamonYates - see what I've added to the end of my answer.  The way you've generated the HTML, the parent of the checkbox will be the `<td>`, but you can use the function I put in my answer to make this easier.  `querySelectorAll()` should work on any element (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll)).

Comment: I like your function that really helps. Can I just ask, in your code above, does the variable price return the actual data inside the price TD? I think it should just want to be sure :-)

Comment: @EamonYates - in my example, `price` is whatever DOM element has the class name `"price"`.  Judging by your code, you will have to get the text out of that DOM element and parse that into a number, being careful to avoid the currency symbol in the front of it.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I have worked out one issue. I am adding the £ symbol via javascript to keep the float as just numbers but have just realised I am accessing the code after I have concatenated the £ symbol. Thats probably why it doesnt add up. I may have shot myself in the foot here.

Comment: @EamonYates - I added to my code example in my answer how to parse the  actual price out of that element.

Comment: Thanks jfriend for all your help. For some reason my code still isnt working but you have answered my initial question and then some. I have learnt a lot from you and I am grateful for that. I will head back to the drawing board with the additional info you have armed me with to figure out whats going wrong. Thanks again for all your help and answering my initial question.